# Creating a darts game and two errors come up "too few argurments in function call" and "game, identifier not found"

Tags: c++, function, identifier

Creating a darts game and two errors come up

```
too few argurments in function call
```

and

```
game, identifier not found
```

I am trying to create a game for an assignment that will make two players "joe and sid" play darts from 301, there are no doubles just a bull and 21 numbers in an array, any help in resolving the question would be greatly appreciated, the code below has four main functions each bringing the score down, first by 50's (bull) then by 20's then by singles, both players must end on a bull and any score that isn't a bull when the score reaches 50, is discarded.

Here is my code below, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int dartScores[] = {20, 1, 18, 4, 13, 6, 10, 15, 2, 17, 3, 19, 7, 16, 8, 11, 14, 9, 12, 5, 20};

void makeThrow( int &score );

int main () 
{
    int joeScore = 301;
    int sidScore = 301;

    for (int i = 0; i< 1000;i++){
    while( joeScore > 0 || sidScore > 0 )
    {
        //do a throw
        game( joeScore);
        game( sidScore);

    }
    // remember to reset the score value

    }


}
void makeThrow_50( int &score, int acc )
{
    if ( rand()%100 < acc )
    {
        score -= 50;
    }
    else
    {
        //select a random
        int missedScore = dartScores[ rand()%20 ];

        // Only reduce score when thrown score is less than remaining score
        if (missedScore > score)
        {
            // Valid dart, take from score
            score -= missedScore;
        }
        else
        {
            // Invalid throw - BUST
            //cout << " BUST ";
        }

        //if (score <0) score=0;
    }
}

void makeThrow_20( int &score, int acc )
{
    if ( rand()%100 < acc )
    {
        score -= 20;
    }
    else
    {
        //select a random
        int missedScore = dartScores[ rand()%20 ];

        // Only reduce score when thrown score is less than remaining score
        if (missedScore > score)
        {
            // Valid dart, take from score
            score -= missedScore;
        }
        else
        {
            // Invalid throw - BUST
            //cout << " BUST ";
        }

        //if (score <0) score=0;
    }
}

void makeThrow_Single( int &score, int acc )
{
    if ( rand()%100 < acc )
    {
        score -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //select a random
        int missedScore = dartScores[ rand()%20 ];

        // Only reduce score when thrown score is less than remaining score
        if (missedScore > score)
        {
            // Valid dart, take from score
            score -= missedScore;
        }
        else
        {
            // Invalid throw - BUST
            //cout << " BUST ";
        }

        //if (score <0) score=0;
    }
}

void makeThrow_bull( int &score, int acc )
{
    if ( rand()%100 < acc )
    {
        score -= 50;
    }
    else
    {
        //select a random
        int missedScore = dartScores[ rand()%20 ];

        // Only reduce score when thrown score is less than remaining score
        if (missedScore > score)
        {
            // Valid dart, take from score
            score -= missedScore;
        }
        else
        {
            // Invalid throw - BUST
            //cout << " BUST ";
        }

        //if (score <0) score=0;
    }
}



int game(int& score, int acc) {
    if (score >= 100)
        makeThrow_50(score, acc);
    else if (score >= 70)
        makeThrow_20(score, 80);
    else if (score >= 51)
        makeThrow_Single(score, 80);
    else 
        makeThrow_bull(score, 80);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need declaration of `game` before the `main`
2. `game` function takes 2 arguments, and you're passing just one (in the `main`)
3. You need `#include <cstdlib>` for `rand()`.
4. I'd also advise `#include <time.h>` and putting `srand (time(NULL))` in the beginning of `main`.

Comment: thank you very much, Kiril Kirov, your help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Either you declare the prototype of `game` or define it before calling it.
2. the function `game` takes two arguments.